big pings caused by "gw01-n.contabo.net" hop on certain web pages
Last weeks I have noticed a problem with delays (150ms) on certain web pages. It only happens in the evenings from around 19:00 GMT+2 until morning. Otherwise the delay is fine - 20ms.
I have run tracert on those webpages and the path is very similar for all of them. The first hop that has high ping (150ms) is "gw01-n.contabo.net [62.115.36.238]". All hops before this point have <20ms, most of the hops after this point have >=150ms.
During the day (until 19:00), the tracert path is same, however delay reported for this cuplrit point is also 20ms. Same thing happens every day for past 2-3 weeks.
Important thing to note is that when I use VPN, the ping for the webpages is OK, because the path is different. Which should rule out that problem is on my side.
I have tried to contact my ISP but they say it's out of their reach.
I have of course tried to restart everything I could. I have tried different devices from my connection. My ISP IP is dynamic, so I have tried to regenerate that also. But nothing helped.
What can I do to solve this? I am still not sure whether the problem is somehow really not on my side, because if the problem was really some faulty international network hop, shouldn't it already be fixed?
pathping
Tracing route to 9gag.com [104.16.106.144]
over a maximum of 30 hops:
  0  mypc [192.168.3.200]
  1  192.168.3.1
  2  192.168.1.1
  3  ** [**]
  4  10.69.249.189
  5  gw01-n.contabo.net [62.115.36.238]
  6  gw01-n.contabo.net [62.115.36.238]
  7  win-bb1-link.ip.twelve99.net [62.115.137.216]
  8  win-b2-link.ip.twelve99.net [62.115.114.185]
  9  cloudflare-ic-381042.ip.twelve99-cust.net [62.115.171.227]
 10  141.101.104.4
 11  104.16.106.144

Computing statistics for 275 seconds...
            Source to Here   This Node/Link
Hop  RTT    Lost/Sent = Pct  Lost/Sent = Pct  Address
  0                                           mypc [192.168.3.200]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  1    0ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  192.168.3.1
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  2    0ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  192.168.1.1
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  3   15ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  ** [**]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  4  ---     100/ 100 =100%   100/ 100 =100%  10.69.249.189
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  5  135ms     1/ 100 =  1%     1/ 100 =  1%  gw01-n.contabo.net [62.115.36.238]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  6  136ms     3/ 100 =  3%     3/ 100 =  3%  gw01-n.contabo.net [62.115.36.238]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  7  139ms     9/ 100 =  9%     9/ 100 =  9%  win-bb1-link.ip.twelve99.net [62.115.137.216]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  8   20ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  win-b2-link.ip.twelve99.net [62.115.114.185]
                                1/ 100 =  1%   |
  9  139ms     8/ 100 =  8%     7/ 100 =  7%  cloudflare-ic-381042.ip.twelve99-cust.net [62.115.171.227]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
 10  105ms     1/ 100 =  1%     0/ 100 =  0%  141.101.104.4
                                6/ 100 =  6%   |
 11  137ms     7/ 100 =  7%     0/ 100 =  0%  104.16.106.144


If you are on Windows, please run pathping and add the output to the question.

What does the hop immediately before this belong to – your ISP or something else?

I have added pathping. The third one is my ISP. The fourth one (10.69.249.189 - before contabo) I have no idea.

@grawity_u1686 Is it possible, that the problematic hop is actually the one before contabo - "10.69.249.189"? It's some local IP, so it may still belong to my ISP.
